# Dash does not keep "sources" filter setting after reboot

Tags: unity-dash, settings

I love that its finally possible in 12.04 to turn off the "recommended software" section (or whatever its called) in the dash... yet my understanding of it was that it would be possible to turn it off permanently.

After I shut down and restart my pc all dash settings have been set back to default and the software center sources are turned on again. This is annoying. Is there a way to turn it off permanently or do I have to live with turning it off in the filter options manually everytime I boot into ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the "sources filter" has to do with turning off the "recommended software" in the apps lens. (All  filter results > Source will return to defaults on fresh login

To disable for real

```
 gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.ApplicationsLens display-available-apps false
```

Answer (score 0):

Just now found out that its possible to permanently block the download recommendations in the dash using the MyUnity app from the software center.