# Dash does not keep source filter beyond a session in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, unity-dash, applications-lens

Is there any way to keep filter settings in the dash beyond a session?

For example, in the application lens I want to disable the Software center source in the list of the available apps. I can do this by going to the filter button and click on the local app source. But If I log out and then log in, this setting is reverted to the default behavior (i.e. display both local *and* available apps).

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/q/127877/54949) it's suggested to use MyUnity, but it's not possible in 12.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer valid for disabling the available apps (so it works as a permanent filter in the dash, not disappearing every new session).

I found this program: [**Unsettings**](http://florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/index.html). It can disable available apps on the application panel.

One has to go to the dash setting panel in the Unsettings application and turn off the switch "Apps for download".

It can also do lots of other nice things for customizing Unity.